# Clarification on Server Messages

Tags: mining, hashrate

I'm a bit new to crypto's in general so please bear with me.

I've been mining for a few days and am starting to build up funds from the pool I am in. I'm running XMRig and, though I have an idea of what the server responses mean, I was wondering if I could get some clarification on the specifics of each message, specifically in reference to my GPU specs. I've outlined four areas below which I would love to hear from you guys about:

[image]

Block 1: for 'new job', does this refer to a block that my GPU is crunching the numbers for? Also, is it good or bad to receive multiple new jobs, but not receive a message such as 'accepted' or 'rejected' from the server? Is there a form of a queue?

Block 2: I'm running an NVIDIA 750ti. Where it says 1320/2700, what does that specify? For example, am I only using that ratio of my total GPU computing processes? Or does that represent other information that requires two numbers (such as 20/20 vision)

Block 3: 'Accepted.' For each accepted, does that mean that mean I've solved part of the algorithm for the monero block, and it brings the pool that much closer to completing a full 'coin'? Also, in a pool, is there any individual benefits for contributing an accepted? Or is it all split evenly (aside from fees)

Block 4: This is pretty self-explanatory. It looks like this displays my average hashrate over 10 seconds, 60 seconds and 15 minutes. But, if this is what it displays, I feel that 31.7 is dismal for my graphics card. When using XMR-Stak and using supportXMR pool, I was averaging ~220.

Thank you for your time and consideration in answering. I hope I haven't missed an article from the Reddit wiki or on here that explains this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Block 1: New Job means that your GPU is starting a new process for the mining. 'diff' means how [difficult the block is](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Difficulty). Can't help for the rest.

Block 2: 1320/2700 MHz(Megahertz) means that your GPU clock is running 1320 MHz out of a max 2700(See block 4).

Block 3: 'Accepted' mean that the result you got might be a viable hash for solving the block.

Block 4: That is low make sure your graphics cards are being forced to work as hard as possible.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough response! I really appreciate your insight. I switched to xmr-stak and have had much better results. Nanopool's web application puts me between 270-400 hashrate. 

A follow up question for you would be: in order to increase the performance to ~2700, would that be something I configure through the NVIDIA software? Or would that likely require me to adjust the threads and what not in my conf file? 

Thanks again for your help!